# Branching based on rating in Microsoft Form

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, sharepoint, microsoft-forms

Is it possible to branch the option based on rating?

Like, if rating is one star, it must go to "What you dislike most" and if rating is 5-star, it must go to "What you like most"

Answer (score 1):

You can add branching logic to your form.

Go to the question for which you want to add branching. Select More settings for question More options button , and then choose Add branching.

On the Branching options page, select the drop-down list next to the question you want to branch.

Select the question that you want to branch to.

More information:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-branching-logic-in-microsoft-forms-16634fda-eddb-44da-856d-6a8213f0d8bb

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question was: To branch to different questions *based on the given rating*.